# Why http server don't return row in database?

Tags: python, postgresql, http, server

I have a function with POST and GET queries in main.py. They should return row with data in table animals, specifically `{rendered animals}`.

In html there is a `{rendered animals}` too. But it show just "No data given". Where is mistake?

[image: my site]

[image: table]

[image: html file]

[image: Get {rendered animals}]

[image: query POST and other]

Comment: Hi, please post your code in text instead of images